# How we run a visual flow( Not Auto Flow) in system mode.

Tags: community, process-builder, visual-flows, systemmodstamp

Requirement..

we want to modify the record of an object without giving System Admin Permission, means at user mode.

How we do the needful, we tried with the help  flow and  process builder but unable to launch the visual flow which has screen through process builder because process builder run's in a system mode.

Can you please suggest the appropriate way to solve the business requirement.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the Flow to update another field, that then triggers the Process Builder that will run in System and modify the record the Running User is unable to modify.

The only other option would be to possibly use an Apex plugin.

There is no way to make your Visual Flow run as System.

Comment: thanks for your quick response, one more help could you please help us How we use Apex Plugin to solve the above problem.

Comment: http://cloudyworlds.blogspot.com/2014/09/invoking-apex-callouts-through-visual.html

Comment: I would recommend trying the PB way if you're not comfortable with Apex.  It would be pretty simple to implement (assuming you don't need to have it happen in a specific order with screens after the update.